# Is it possible to merge two user profiles with different email ids?

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I had created a Stack Overflow account 4-5 years back using an email id provided by the company for which I used to work back then.

I no longer work in that company and no longer have access to email address. So after a while I created this Stack Overflow account with my personnel email which I am using since then.

I came across the merge feature and gave it a try by filling in a form.

But as per the procedure it sends out two identical emails to both accounts to verify and confirm the merge.

As I no longer haver access to the older email address, I will not receive the second email by which I can merge two accounts.

Is there another way I can achieve this?

Comment: Not in a standard way. As the answer in the other question says, the only option is to contact the team.